# How do I enable authentication for an Office add-in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-office

I'm working on an Excel add-in that enables users to post data to a database.  That same database is also part of an ASP.NET website and has Membership Provider tables.  What I'd like to do is integrate the Excel add-in with the authentication for the website so that I can associate the data with the user from whom it came.  The problem I'm solving is one of attribution, not security.  So I'm open to other possible solutions that do not involve the use of a username and password.  For example, I've considered giving each installation of the add-in a guid that gets registered with the database when the program is initially installed.  I don't know if this is a good solution.  And I don't know where/how I would persist the guid locally on each machine.  My gut tells me the simplest solution is to somehow tap into the existing ASP.NET Membership Provider for the website since the website and add-in share a database.  If it's possible to do that, please explain how.  If not, or if you can propose a better solution, please explain what that solution is and how it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post helps: [WCF, ASP.NET Membership Provider and Authentication Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112/wcf-asp-net-membership-provider-and-authentication-service). It describes that you can extract the cookie out of a wcf Auth call and reuse it

**Edit:** Another URL you might have a look at: http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2011/01/25/forms-authentication-with-client-application-services.aspx